# NPM returns an error related to Ubuntu version?

Tags: ubuntu, npm

I'm kind of a beginner with NPM. I get this error when I run `npm install`:

```
[ERROR] npm ERR! Linux 5.4.0-72-generic
[ERROR] npm ERR! argv "/mypath/node/node" "/mypath/node/node/node/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "install"
[ERROR] npm ERR! node v5.9.0
[ERROR] npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
[ERROR] npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument
```

I have absolutely no idea what's going on. Can't find anything on internet. Any ideas?

This is my npm version output:

```
 $ npm version
{
  npm: '7.11.1',
  node: '14.12.0',
  v8: '8.4.371.19-node.16',
  uv: '1.39.0',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  ares: '1.16.0',
  modules: '83',
  nghttp2: '1.41.0',
  napi: '7',
  llhttp: '2.1.2',
  openssl: '1.1.1g',
  cldr: '37.0',
  icu: '67.1',
  tz: '2020a',
  unicode: '13.0'
}
```

My Ubuntu is:

```
Release 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa) 64-bit
Kernel Linux 5.4.0-72-generic x86_64
MATE 1.24.0
```

Comment: " Missing required argument" seems important. Are you in a directory with a `package.json`?

Comment: I may need to update this question. I was just able to build. But not they way I'm supposed. I have a maven projects with multiple nested java module, plus some front end module. From maven the front end code is being built using some npm plugin. From mvn command I get the errors, but running the npm stuff separately inside each sub project, works. Even after running the separate npm commands, the general maven command works.